# HTML tables - Rowspan cell attribute syntax

Tags: html, css, html-table

Colspan works, rowspan doesn't. Anyone know why?
picture: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KkX5MTWOEfCNyz1tg2_s9DZ3EVyAHRAc
I've tried doing things like deleteing cells from the above row but that hasn't worked either.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Lab8: Tables</title>
</head>

<body>

<table width=100 style="border-style:solid; border-width:50px; border-color: 
#00f0ff; border-spacing: 10px;" border="50px">
<tr>
 <td style="color:blue; padding:20px;">cell 16</td>
 <td style="color:blue; padding:20px;">cell 17</td>
 <td style="color:blue; padding:20px;">cell 18</td>
 <td style="color:blue; padding:20px;">cell 19</td>
 <td style="color:blue; padding:20px;">cell 20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td style="color:blue; padding:20px;">cell 21</td>
 <td style="color:blue; padding:20px;">cell 22</td>
 <td style="color:blue; padding:20px;">cell 23</td>
 <td style="color:blue; padding:20px;" colspan="2" rowspan="2">cell 24</td>
</tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your XHTML is invalid. Use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: It's also not well-formed, with the unquoted width=100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rowspan` means "This cell occupies this row and the **next** row".

There is no next row in your HTML.